# Stata code taking too long to run when performing synthetic control method

Tags: performance, statistics, stata, economics

Currently working on a paper for class where I'm estimating the effects of natural disasters on birth rates. I'm using the synthetic control method to analyze these effects using the stata package "synth2." The data is clean, the code (I think) is all correct, the only problem is that it just takes eons to run – and in some instances – just won't run at all. Let me share the code:

```
synth2 loggedbirths loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m1)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m2)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m3)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m4)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m5)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m6)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m7)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m8)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m9)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m10)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m11)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2009m12)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m1)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m2)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m3)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m4)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m5)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m6)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m7)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m8)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m9)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m10)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m11)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2010m12)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m1)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m2)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m3)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m4)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m5)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m6)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m7)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m8)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m9)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m10)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m11)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2011m12)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m1)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m2)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m3)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m4)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m5)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m6)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m7)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m8)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m9)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m10)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m11)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2012m12)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m1)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m2)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m3)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m4)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m5)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m6)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m7)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m8)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m9)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m10)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m11)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2013m12)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m1)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m2)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m3)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m4)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m5)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m6)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m7)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m8)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m9)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m10)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m11)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2014m12)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m1)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m2)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m3)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m4)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m5)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m6)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m7)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m8)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m9)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m10)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m11)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2015m12)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2016m1)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2016m2)') loggedbirths(`=tm(2016m3)')  marriages(`=tm(2009m1)') marriages(`=tm(2009m2)') marriages(`=tm(2009m3)') marriages(`=tm(2009m4)') marriages(`=tm(2009m5)') marriages(`=tm(2009m6)') marriages(`=tm(2009m7)') marriages(`=tm(2009m8)') marriages(`=tm(2009m9)') marriages(`=tm(2009m10)') marriages(`=tm(2009m11)') marriages(`=tm(2009m12)') marriages(`=tm(2010m1)') marriages(`=tm(2010m2)') marriages(`=tm(2010m3)') marriages(`=tm(2010m4)') marriages(`=tm(2010m5)') marriages(`=tm(2010m6)') marriages(`=tm(2010m7)') marriages(`=tm(2010m8)') marriages(`=tm(2010m9)') marriages(`=tm(2010m10)') marriages(`=tm(2010m11)') marriages(`=tm(2010m12)') marriages(`=tm(2011m1)') marriages(`=tm(2011m2)') marriages(`=tm(2011m3)') marriages(`=tm(2011m4)') marriages(`=tm(2011m5)') marriages(`=tm(2011m6)') marriages(`=tm(2011m7)') marriages(`=tm(2011m8)') marriages(`=tm(2011m9)') marriages(`=tm(2011m10)') marriages(`=tm(2011m11)') marriages(`=tm(2011m12)') marriages(`=tm(2012m1)') marriages(`=tm(2012m2)') marriages(`=tm(2012m3)') marriages(`=tm(2012m4)') marriages(`=tm(2012m5)') marriages(`=tm(2012m6)') marriages(`=tm(2012m7)') marriages(`=tm(2012m8)') marriages(`=tm(2012m9)') marriages(`=tm(2012m10)') marriages(`=tm(2012m11)') marriages(`=tm(2012m12)') marriages(`=tm(2013m1)') marriages(`=tm(2013m2)') marriages(`=tm(2013m3)') marriages(`=tm(2013m4)') marriages(`=tm(2013m5)') marriages(`=tm(2013m6)') marriages(`=tm(2013m7)') marriages(`=tm(2013m8)') marriages(`=tm(2013m9)') marriages(`=tm(2013m10)') marriages(`=tm(2013m11)') marriages(`=tm(2013m12)') marriages(`=tm(2014m1)') marriages(`=tm(2014m2)') marriages(`=tm(2014m3)') marriages(`=tm(2014m4)') marriages(`=tm(2014m5)') marriages(`=tm(2014m6)') marriages(`=tm(2014m7)') marriages(`=tm(2014m8)') marriages(`=tm(2014m9)') marriages(`=tm(2014m10)') marriages(`=tm(2014m11)') marriages(`=tm(2014m12)') marriages(`=tm(2015m1)') marriages(`=tm(2015m2)') marriages(`=tm(2015m3)') marriages(`=tm(2015m4)') marriages(`=tm(2015m5)') marriages(`=tm(2015m6)') marriages(`=tm(2015m7)') marriages(`=tm(2015m8)') marriages(`=tm(2015m9)') marriages(`=tm(2015m10)') marriages(`=tm(2015m11)') marriages(`=tm(2015m12)') marriages(`=tm(2016m1)') marriages(`=tm(2016m2)') marriages(`=tm(2016m3)'), trunit(43) trperiod(`=tm(2016m4)') counit(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,39,47) nested allopt placebo(unit cut(2)) sigf(6) loo frame(kum) savegraph(kum) postperiod(`=tm(2016m4)' `=tm(2016m5)',`=tm(2016m6)',`=tm(2016m7)',`=tm(2016m8)',`=tm(2016m9)',`=tm(2016m10)',`=tm(2016m11)',`=tm(2016m12)',`=tm(2017m1)',`=tm(2017m2)',`=tm(2017m3)',`=tm(2017m4)',`=tm(2017m5)',`=tm(2017m6)',`=tm(2017m7)',`=tm(2017m8)',`=tm(2017m9)',`=tm(2017m10)',`=tm(2017m11)',`=tm(2017m12)',`=tm(2018m1)',`=tm(2018m2)',`=tm(2018m3)',`=tm(2018m4)',`=tm(2018m5)',`=tm(2018m6)')
```

Yeah, I know it's a lot. The "marriages" and past values of logged births are my covariates, for context. The only code I run before this is just cd'ing into the file with the dataset anad declaring the model as a panel data sorted by month and ID (my unit of analysis is a Japanese Prefecture). I have tried removing "allopt" but doesn't seem to speed things up. Does anyone have any advice on how I can make this code run faster?

Comment: If you have Stata MP, you can try https://github.com/bquistorff/synth_runner with the parallel option.

Comment: You can also try https://github.com/Daniel-Pailanir/sdidw, which is written in Mata and is not a wrapper for synth.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I would comment with these questions but I don't have the reputation yet.

Have you tried:

1. Dropping any variables from your dataset that you do not need in the regression? This frees up more space than most tend to realize.
2. Storing each of the covariates in a local or global, e.g. `local covariates "X1 X2 X3 ... XN"` and then calling it in the regression?
3. Suppressing the output with `qui`?

Comment: Just a guess but #2 and #3 seem most unlikely to me to produce speed-ups.